# Configure SQL always on Configuration for SharePoint 2013 Server Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

Configured SharePoint 2013 farm with SQL server 2012 AOAG group.

When the SQL database fails over to the secondary instance . I get a message as follows

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but we've made the site read only while we're making some improvements.

It seems like it is in read mode.

Is it just a warning that can be ignored or am I missing an important step during configuration.

I have configured the SQL AOAG(Always on Availability group) in Synchronous mode.

Steps so far

- Installed SharePoint binaries and configured SharePoint with SQL server
- Installed SQL on two SQL servers. Configured AOAG group with a Listener
- Configured SQL alias name  for SharePoint Always configuration in Synchronous mode
- When the  SQL instance on the first primary instance is stopped. The secondary SQL server automatically becomes the primary and SharePoint successfully renders but it has the message.
- In SQL the  databases appear as synchronized on the primary and secondary instance.
- Manual fail-over and using fail-over wizard have the same effect as shown below

. See Image below
[image]

I also can see the following critical error in the ulsViewer Logs which implies it is an an read only mode

***SharePoint Cannot update database on SQL Server instance SQL01.  Database (....)  is read/only. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Failed to update SharePoint_Config database because the database is read-only.***

Comment: is it really marked it readonly or just warning? are you able to failover to secondary server? did you try to manual failover?

Comment: Did you ensure that the appropriate user accounts for the databases were created on the secondary replica of the AlwaysOn AG? Have you ensured that the accounts have appropriate rights in SQL Server to the databases that are part of the AG?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any particular permissions that i need to check.

Comment: Essentially you're looking to replicate the permissions on the primary server onto the secondary server, so for each login/database combination, ensure that the permissions on the secondary server are configured the same. Generally, as long as you've added all of the same logins used on the primary server onto the secondary server, the permissions sort themselves out, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Check also that what the status of the databases on the secondary replica are. They should read 'synchronised'.

Answer (score 0):

Please Migrate the SharePoint login accounts to other SQL Box, so both SQL Instances share the Same Logins

Answer (score 0):

> The issue got fixed automatically after restarting all FARM servers.